# Facebook Messenger Bot, Send multiple Image Attachment

Tags: facebook-messenger

I'm creating a Facebook bot, where the bot sends out 5 image attachment.

Below is the Json template to send out 1 image

```
"message":{
"attachment":{
  "type":"image",
  "payload":{
    "url":"https://petersapparel.com/img/shirt.png"
  }
}
```

}

I Need Json formate to send multiple image attachment on Facebook messenger api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either send out several messages to your user in a `for loop` or you could use a [list template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/list-template) to send the photos (and captions) together, but it would render differently.

Comment: cant we send multiple text msgs in once

Comment: the `list template` is deprecated